# Is there a society of thinking and free droids in the Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars

Is there a society of thinking and free droids in the Old Republic? In the Star Wars galaxy, is the threat of a technological singularity ever speculated on? Is there a planet sized A.I. machine and finally-artificial animal intelligence?

Comment: You are asking many questions. I suggest you split them up. Also, I took the liberty of changing the title to make it more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a planet sized A.I. machine and finally-artificial animal intelligence?

Sort of and sort of.

In X-Wing series of books, there is a [project Chubar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Project_Chubar) by scientists working for warlord Zsinj, who manage to significantly elevate the intelligence of various less-intelligent species. They produce a [genius-level intellect in Gamorrean](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Voort_saBinring) (whose baseline as species is near-idiocy); and a good intelligence in an [Ewok](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kolot) (who are known to not be intelligent enough to pilot a starfighter, ordinarily).

---

As far as AI machine, depends on the size you care about

There was an "asteroid-sized" (it was said to be slightly bigger than "Executor SSD") drednaught called "[Eye_of_Palpatine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_Palpatine)" which had an AI controlling it called [**The Will**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Will). It was featured in "*Children of the Jedi*" book. It was Palpatine's first superweapon and precursor to Death Stars.

If you go slightly smaller, "*X-Wing: The Bacta War*" had Alderaanian War Frigate "[Another Chance](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Another_Chance)" and its Thranta-class War Cruiser [Valiant](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Valiant_%28Thranta-class%29) ; both were flown automatically. Whether there were true AIs flying them isn't made clear.

Comment: Also, as another answer kind of alludes to: the implied attack of Abominor that caused Vong to become as they became, can possibly be considered as allusion to singularity. If you squint hard enough.

Comment: SWEET. I squinted and I found it!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not in the Old Republic itself. There are two separate droid societies in the Unknown Regions, the [Silentium](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Silentium) and the [Abominor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Abominor). Both are originally extra-galactic in origin, and it is implied - though never explicitly stated - that they are from the Yuuzhan Vong home galaxy. It was probably the Abominor who invaded Yuuzhan'tar, provoking the Yuuzhan Vong counterattack that led to the eventual Yuuzhan Vong war in the *Star Wars* galaxy.
2. Not really. There are droids that achieved sapience and became threats, such as [IG-88](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/IG-88_assassin_droid), but no singularity as such.
3. No. The largest droids ever created were the aforementioned Silentium, and larger constructs, such as the Death Stars, weren't entirely AI-based.
4. No. To my knowledge, there has never been an artificial animal intelligence in a *Star Wars* production of any kind.